# order_new.html email template by payment method

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

I try to modify some text in the order_new.html if the customer pay by a custom payment method.

For example, if he pay with 'tati' payment method, I want to remove a sentence of the mail template.

Can I do that, I try to add conditions on the template but it doesn't work..

Thanks.

Comment: please attach your code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding condition directly in the email template, you can replace your "sentence" with a block:

```
{{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='Vendor_Module::email/order/info.phtml' order=$order}}
```

Then in your template `email/order/info.phtml`, you can use the condition however you want:

```
if ($this->getData('order')->getPayment()->getMethod() != 'tati') {
    echo __('The sentence you want to show to any payment method but "tati"');
}
```